# What is the difference between coercion and overloading?

Tags: oop, theory

I am confused about the terms.  from what i understand, coercion is when the language converts the variable types and overloading when the language uses the same symbols for more than one purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us, for a moment, compare a computer language to a bakery: When the `bake` function is overloaded, you can have many different ovens (implementations), one for bread, one for pizza, etc. With coercion, you need only one oven, but for some things you want to bake you need a little gadget ("coercion function") to make it fit in that one oven.

So with overloading there are multiple implementations (ovens) determined by the argument type (food), with coercion there are multiple coercion functions (gadgets) from each argument type (food) to one single type (the one that the oven needs)

Whether you have many gadgets, or many ovens, they should be uniquely determined by the type of food. You'll have a problem when you e.g have an oven for Italian food, and another for food that contains tomatoes: what to do with a pizza? This is what e.g. Haskell programmers know as "overlapping typeclasses". It can sometimes be solved, e.g. if one oven is strictly more specialized than another (one for Italian food, and another for Tuscan food)

Answer (score 0):

From a very general perspective, the main difference is that whereas *overloading* is explicit (controlled by you, the programmer), *type coercion* is implicit (controlled by the compiler).